# Cannot access jquery Json POST parameters in PHP but working with Ajax and Normal post

Tags: php, json, post

When i Send POST parameters Through AJax i get a response back as required in the following url but not through Json. I have even done a print_r($_POST) to check at the server  and get a blank array in Json. Can you tell me what i am doing wrong. In other pages my Json are working fine the same way.

url: http://www.ajatus.in/ajatus_templates/Templaton/wp-content/plugins/realestate/registrationJson.php

---

Ajax Code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function showUser()
    {

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
       var title="My title";
      var fname="Asish";
      var lname="Mohanty";
      var city="BBSR";
      var conNo="9475654563";
      var pwd="asish";
      var email="asish@gmail.com";
      var state="Odisha";
      var country="India";


     xmlhttp.open("POST","http://www.ajatus.in/ajatus_templates/Templaton/wp-content/plugins/realestate/registrationJson.php",true);
     xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     xmlhttp.send("title="+title+"&fname="+fname+"&lname="+lname+"&city="+city+"&conNo="+conNo+"&pwd="+pwd+"&email="+email+"&state="+state+"&country="+country);

    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form method="post">
    <input type="button" value="SUBMIT" onClick="showUser()">

    </form>
    <br />
    <div id="txtHint" align="center"><b></b></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

---

Json code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function showUser() {
      var title="My title";
      var fname="Asish";
      var lname="Mohanty";
      var city="BBSR";
      var conNo="9475654563";
      var pwd="asish";
      var email="asish@gmail.com";
      var state="Odisha";
      var country="India";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //the url where you want to sent the userName and password to
            url: 'http://www.ajatus.in/ajatus_templates/Templaton/wp-content/plugins/realestate/registrationJson.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            //json object to sent to the authentication url
            data: JSON.stringify({ "title" : title,"fname" : fname,"lname": lname,"city" : city,"conNo": conNo,"pwd" : pwd,"email": email,"state" : state,"country" : country }),
            success: function (data) {

            alert(data); 
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form method="post">
    <input type="button" value="SUBMIT" onClick="showUser()">

    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_POST` handles `Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` not JSON to get the JSON use

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Comment: The same code however works in another page which is used for login.
Can you please explain where i can put the code $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); to make it work.

i need to receive the data in PHP file and do a registration and have access to the server also.

Comment: @GirishSahu after `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));` just use `$data` instead of `$_POST`.

Comment: Thanks @Musa It worked. But i have a doubt How did the same work for another Page The code is :
function showUser() {
 var email="swati@gmail.com";
     var pwd="swati";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://www.ajatus.in/ajatus_templates/Templaton/wp-content/plugins/realestate/loginJson.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        //json object to sent to the authentication url
        data: JSON.stringify({ "email": email, "pwd" : pwd }),
        success: function (data) {

        alert(data); 
        }
    });
}