# How can I retrieve json stringified objects in php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, stringify

I sent some data to the server using the code snippet below, but I do not know how to retrieve the returned array using `PHP`. Thanks for any suggestion.

```
$('.ticket-row').each(function() {
tickets.push({ id : $(this).attr('id'),
              no : $(this).find('#no').text(),
              c_name : $(this).find('#c_name').val(),
              next_of_kin: $(this).find('#next_of_kin').val(),
              address : $(this).find('#address').val(),
              seat_no : $(this).find('#seat_no').val(),
              fare : $(this).find('#fare').val() });
});

$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '**URL_HERE**',
    data : JSON.stringify(tickets),
    dataType : 'json'
});
```

Comment: have you tried looking in $_POST?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot access jquery Json POST parameters in PHP but working with Ajax and Normal post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890448/cannot-access-jquery-json-post-parameters-in-php-but-working-with-ajax-and-norma)

Comment: @thescientist yes, I get the following error "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

Comment: @Chibuzo try setting `contentType:'application/json',` in your ajax request.

Comment: you used the right tag - "json-decode", the PHP function is called http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php Can you show us the PHP part?

Comment: @Chibuzo try data: "d="+JOSN.stringify, and on PHP side use "$_POST["d"]

Comment: @Musa and EGOrecords thanks for the suggestion and concern, the answer below has cured my bewilderment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to use something like

```
'posted_data=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(tickets))
```

Then, on the PHP side you can get it with

```
$posted_data = $_POST['posted_data'];
$data = json_decode($posted_data);
```

Instead of using `JSON.stringify`, you could also use the JSON as the data and jQuery will convert it to a query string as part of the request.  Then, you can use the individual components in `$_POST`.

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked well for me, I can figure out the rest.